# String replace different result

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
$string = "[abc] my [efg] best [hij]";
```

first [] change to Hi.
second [] change to Hello.
third [] change to World.

The entire string are dynamic. (It is always show different result.) 
Example:

```
$string = "[iii] my my [ooo] yes to all [eee]";
$string = "[abc] lovely [efg] [hij]";
$string = "[abc] my [efg] best of the the the the [hij]. That Right.";
```

I can tried this code, but it replace all to same value.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/',"Hi",$string );
```

Once replace will become Hi Hello World. Can str_replace string to that?

Comment: Hi change `$string = "test tests test";` to `$string = "test test test";` or change at `second test change to Hello.` your question is with conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

```
$string = "[abc] my [efg] best [hij]"; 
$repl = array('Hi', 'Hello', 'World');
foreach($repl as $word) {
    $string = preg_replace('/\[[^\]]+\]/', $word, $string, 1);
}
echo $string,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Hi my Hello best World
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `explode`:

```
<?php
    $string = "[abc] my [efg] best [hij]";         

    $ar = explode(" ", $string);             

    $ar[0] = 'Hi';                       
    $ar[2] = 'Hello';                       
    $ar[4] = 'World';

    echo implode(' ', $ar); //Hi my Hello best World
```

Comment: Very sorry to confuse you. I realize I ask wrong question. I had edited my question. Once again sorry

Comment: @learnallskill No problem. I edit answer, and you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You want the whole text to change so no need condition here..

```
$string = "[abc] [efg] [hij]";
$change = "Hi Hello World";
echo str_replace($string,$change,$string);
```